# LXML webpage scraping, mal-formated html

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the article text from this web site http://sana.sy/eng/21/2013/01/07/pr-460536.htm , but its HTML is mal-formatted. Can Anyone show me how to get it right.

```
this is the code
import urllib2
from lxml import etree
import StringIO

speachesurls = ["http://sana.sy/eng/21/2013/01/07/pr-460536.htm", "http://sana.sy/eng/21/2012/06/04/pr-423234.htm", "http://sana.sy/eng/21/2012/01/12/pr-393338.htm"]


# scrape the speaches

for url in speachesurls:
    result = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html = result.read()
    parser = etree.HTMLParser()
    tree = etree.parse(StringIO.StringIO(html), parser)
    xpath = "//html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/p"
    a = tree.find(xpath)
    print a.text_content()
```

Comment: Use a different parser? BeautifulSoup can use different parsers and give you the same API (albeit without XPath support) for all of them. `html5lib` could well do a better job of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem with lxml or malformed html, lxml's html parser *can* deal with that.

Your code works fine, it's just that your xpath expression doesn't match anything, so `a` will be `None`.